# Resize UIImageView based on HTTP image response in Swift

Tags: swift, http, uiimageview, resize, size

I have an UIImageView in my story board and I am using SDWebImage to set image the property.

```
imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(photoURL)
```

How could I update the UIImageView size to match this image that is coming as a response from a HTTP request?

Comment: did you tried imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit or if you using collectionView set ur cell content mode to scaleaspectFit.hope this help....

Answer (score 0):

After you load the image into the imageView:

```
var frame = imageView.frame
let imageSize = imageView.image.size
frame.size.width = imageSize.width
frame.size.height = imageSize.height
imageView.frame = frame
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the help of autoLayout :-
Just give the leading and trailing constraint to your image View and rest image view automatically handle